# How to call method of the installed module into another installed module in Odoo 11?

Tags: odoo-11

I am using Odoo 11 and I want to use a method  of 
`Sale module > models > sale > SaleOrder > action_confirm method` 
into 
`Mail module > models > mail_mail > MailMail > send method`

How to use the method of a module to another module method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method of a module that you are describing is just a method will be part of an Odoo model, `sale.order` in this case so if you wanna call it you just need a `sale.order` record to call the method. For example:

```
order_id = 3
order = self.env['sale.order'].browse(order_id)
order.action_confirm()
```

You could use that code anywhere you wanna use it. Normally in an Odoo method that provides the `self.env` access to the Odoo models.